# How to record audio instruments in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, core-audio, audio-streaming

I want to record a virtual instrument in iOS that creates buffers which I can stream later on. But for this I need to create a recording buffer . I have a virtual piano that plays mp3 file on button click. But I really dont have any idea of internally recording the pieces the user plays. I have used a microphone recording for this but its very noisy and doesnt give a clean recording. Apps like garage band have such a feature . So i dont thinks its impossible. Can anyone guide me through this query?

I have tried [Audio Engine](https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine) but the sample code doesnt work for some reason. The code runs but nothing happens when i push the play button. No audio is played.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

to your project

and add delegate `AVAudioRecorderDelegate` to your **.h** file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioRecorder *Audiorecorder;
```

In **.m** file *(here `self.audioFileName`is `NSString` )*

**This is snippet of code :**

```
NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];        
        [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

        //Now that we have our settings we are going to instanciate an instance of our recorder instance.
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss"];
        self.audioFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.audioFileName ];
        NSLog(@"%@",path);
        NSURL *recordedTmpFile = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
        NSLog(@"%@",recordedTmpFile);

        //Setup the recorder to use this file and record to it.
        if(self.Audiorecorder != nil)
        {
            [self.Audiorecorder stop];
            self.Audiorecorder = nil;
        }

        NSError * error;
        self.Audiorecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];
        //NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
        [self.Audiorecorder setDelegate:self];
        [self.Audiorecorder prepareToRecord];       

        //Start the actual Recording
        [self.Audiorecorder peakPowerForChannel:8];
        [self.Audiorecorder updateMeters];
        self.Audiorecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [self.Audiorecorder record];
```

Comment: AVAudioRecorder doesnt create buffers.Which I want to stream later.@iPatel

Comment: I tried using Mixer Host Apple's example but i think so that for variable size audio file it does not work so any one has any other idea do share it